# Is there any thing similar to mongo.model(); in DynamoDB...?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-dynamodb

I want to create Dynamo db tables in node.js script.

In short i want dynamo-db code equivalent to following:

```js
var mongo = require('mongoose');
var MongoDB = mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test').connection;
MongoDB.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err.message); });
MongoDB.once('open', function() {
  console.log("DynamoDB connection open");
});
var userschema = mongo.Schema({
 name: String,
 nickname: {type: String,default: ''},
 email: String,
 phone: String,
 type: String,
 port : String,
 deviceRegId: {type: String,default: ''},
 assignFlag: Number,
 created: {type: Date,default: Date.now} ,
 lastmsg : {type: String,default: ''} ,
 lasttime : {type: Date,default: Date.now} ,
 loginStatus : {type: Boolean,default: false} ,
 isOnline : {type: Boolean,default: false} ,
 chats: [{
   from: String,
   msgfrom: Number,
   name: String,
   msg: String,
   date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
   flag: Number
 }]
});
var agent = mongo.model('naveen', userschema);
exports.mongo = mongo;
exports.agent = agent;
```

I am trying to search similar Dynamo function, but could not find any. Any help would be of great use.

Comment: How about dynamoose https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamoose

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code to **create the table if not present and create an item on it with default values**.

Please note that you can't have empty value for an attribute on DynamoDB. For example, the nickname can't be set as empty string by default.

For any attribute, if you set an empty value and try to insert the data, DynamoDB will throw a validation exception.

**So, default can't be empty string.**

**Code:-**

```
var dynamoose = require('dynamoose');
dynamoose.AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'AKID',
    secretAccessKey: 'SECRET',
    region: 'us-east-1'
});
dynamoose.local();
var Schema = dynamoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        hashKey: true
    },
    nickname: String,
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    type: String,
    port: String,
    deviceRegId: String,
    assignFlag: Number,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    lastmsg: { type: String },
    lasttime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    loginStatus: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isOnline: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    chats: [{
        from: String,
        msgfrom: Number,
        name: String,
        msg: String,
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        flag: Number
    }]
},
    {
        throughput: { read: 15, write: 5 }
    });
var Table = dynamoose.Table;

var UserDetails = dynamoose.model('UserDetails', userSchema);

var user1 = new UserDetails({ name: 'John' });

user1.save(function (err) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log('Added a new item');
});
```

**Sample item created:-**

Date value is stored as Number.

[image: Sample item inserted]

Comment: thanks for help...now I am developing my code.If I get any error i will let you  know...

Comment: Was the above answer useful ?